# How to make two pages work together to get data and display it from another script? [flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart

So right now what my program is doing is first display the home page and then get the User Input and then get the data from a rest api that I wrote, now what I want to do is have another page that displays the data that the api returned. The api takes some time to load the data so I also want to make a loading screen while it gets the data.

https://pastebin.com/2BZqSmfM Home page code

```
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() async {
                      output = await set_data();
                    });
                  },
```

This code sets the data. I tried adding some code to change the page to some other page but it didn't let the code below it to run.

https://pastebin.com/Jdg0uUUy

Code to get the data.

You can see in it it gets the data in an async function, and the page in which I want to display it does not have any async function so I could get the data from it with an await.

There's nothing much interesting in the third page,

https://pastebin.com/gm6qZiw9

except maybe this:

```
 child: Text(                 //display the fetched data in this
              'display data here',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
              ),
            ),
```

where I want to display the text I got.

So what I need to do this is first get the user input through the first and then get the data from the api and display it on the second page, this all happens when the button on the first page is clicked and a transition happens from the first page to the second page with a spinkit loading screen between them, also the loading screen should be there until the data completely loads and the 2nd page should have the fetched data already when it loads and turns on. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go, I edited your code with the solution.
You basically declare an async method, that will set a loading variable, fetch the data, and finally navigate to your second screen and passing to it the results of the fetch call.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home();

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool loading = false;
  String url = '';
  String url2 = '';
  var data;
  var data2;
  var name = '';
  var id = '';

  String output = 'Initial Output';
  bool isLoading = false;

  Future<void> loadDataAndNavigate() async {
    setState(() => isLoading = true);

    output = await set_data();

    isLoading = false;

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const Item(output: output),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(235, 146, 255, 127),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'CHPR6',
          style: TextStyle(
            shadows: <Shadow>[
              Shadow(
                offset: Offset(2.0, 3.0),
                blurRadius: 3,
                color: Color.fromARGB(104, 0, 0, 0),
              ),
            ],
            fontSize: 25,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text(
                'Github',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)),
              )),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 8,
          ),
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text(
                'Found A Bug?',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)),
              )),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 4,
          ),
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text(
                'X',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)),
              ))
        ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: isLoading
            ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
            : Container(
                child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
                  AnimatedTextKit(
                    animatedTexts: [
                      TypewriterAnimatedText(
                        'FIND THE CHEAPEST PRODUCT AVAILABLE',
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                          shadows: <Shadow>[
                            Shadow(
                              offset: Offset(2.0, 3.0),
                              blurRadius: 3,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(104, 0, 0, 0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        speed: const Duration(milliseconds: 120),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 100,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 1100,
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(235, 28, 58, 26),
                            width: 1.5,
                          )),
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(235, 28, 58, 26),
                            width: 1.5,
                          )),
                          hintText: 'Search Now',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255), fontSize: 20)),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                      controller: textController,
                      maxLines: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 60),
                  Container(
                    height: 55,
                    width: 220,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromARGB(235, 28, 58, 26), borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4))),
                    child: TextButton(
                        // sets the output variable
                        onPressed: () async => loadDataAndNavigate(),
                        child: const Text(
                          'Search Now',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white),
                        )),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    output, // sets the data
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.green),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                  )
                ]),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Item extends StatelessWidget {
  const Item({required String output});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have questions.